# AppsFlyer не перекидывает в Google Play

Tags: android

Подскажите, пожалуйста, первый раз сталкиваюсь с AppsFlyer. Deeplink работает, но только если приложение уже установлено.. Как сделать, чтоб перекидывал в Google Play, если приложение ещё не установлено?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Мало информации. Приведите все детали настройки дип-линков. Скорее всего вы где-то что-то не прописали; например - собственно адрес приложения в маркете.

Comment: Адрес в коде где-то надо указывать? говорю же, первый раз, а инфу нормальную пока не нашла..

Comment: Это нужно указывать на сайте. Там, вроде, в 2 местах надо смотреть. В собственно диплинке и в OneLink (вроде так называется) Вот где-то там, вроде в одном месте, и надо это прописывать. Точно я не помню, но видел как это там настраивали и всё работало. Пока приложение не установлено ничего из кода никак не повлияет на правильность перехода по ссылке. Засим надо на сайте править, не в коде.

Comment: спасибо, буду методом тыка пробовать))))